# How do I restrict the number of columns used in an INSERT when using EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, dto

Let's say you have an Entity with 26 columns.  It matches the corresponding table which also has 26 columns.

From time to time I would like to be able to send fewer columns in an INSERT (Add) operation than are specified in the entity because of certain business rules (In our case we have a trigger on a table that will automatically populate certain fields with data.  We routinely leave those columns out of our INSERT statements)

I know that I can use DTOs to restrict the number of columns returned, but how do I restrict the number of columns sent?

Answer (score 1):

If there are operations that would insert entities that only provide a subset of columns (non-null-able for example) then you can consider using a bounded context with an entity declaration for just those applicable columns. The bounded context is a smaller, single-purpose context for reading and writing data since a single EF context does not support multiple entity definitions to a single table.

Comment: Thanks.  Your suggestion lead me to a Julie Lerman artticle [Shrink EF Models with DDD Bounded Contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx)   I have a lot to learn as I'm new at this, but I can see this is the right way to go.